# beautifulsoup parse html file contents

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have 30911 html files in a folder. I need to (1) check whether it contains a tag:

```
<strong>123</strong>
```

and (2) extract the following contents until this section is ended.

But I found a problem is that some of them ended before

```
<strong>567</strong>
```

And some of them do not have such tag, which is ended before

```
<strong>89/strong> or others(that I do not know because I cant check 30K+files)
```

It also has different p p_number in each file and sometime does not have id

So first I use beautifulsoup to search, but I don't know how to do the next extracting contents

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(fo, "lxml")
m = soup.find("strong", string=re.compile("123"))
```

Btw, is is possible to save the content as txt format, but it will look like in html format?

```
line 1
line 2
...
lin 50
```

If use p.get_text(strip=true), it's all together.

```
line1 content line2 content ... 
line50 content....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can first find the starting point - a `p` element that has a `strong` element with "Question-and-Answer Session" text. Then, you can iterate over the `p` element's [next siblings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) until you hit the one which has a `strong` element with "Copyright policy" text.

Complete reproduceable example:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<body>
    <p class="p p4" id="question-answer-session">
      <strong>
       Question-and-Answer Session
      </strong>
    </p>

    <p class="p p4">
       Hi John and Greg, good afternoon. contents....
    </p>

    <p class="p p14">
      <strong>
       Copyright policy:
      </strong>
      other content about the policy....
    </p>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

def find_question_answer(tag):
    return tag.name == 'p' and tag.find("strong", text=re.compile(r"Question-and-Answer Session"))

question_answer = soup.find(find_question_answer)
for p in question_answer.find_next_siblings("p"):
    if p.find("strong", text=re.compile(r"Copyright policy")):
        break

    print(p.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Hi John and Greg, good afternoon. contents....
```

Comment: If I write the content into a new html file, the format will be messed up though.

Comment: @MichaelLin okay, which part do you want to write to a file?

Comment: I think I solve it, I use 
    p.prettify().encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8', 'ignore') then it only save the content before copyright

Comment: But as I mentioned in my question, there is another tag "related:", so it could be either "copyright" or "related", anyway to solve it?

Comment: @MichaelLin one option would be to adjust the regex: `re.compile(r"(Copyright policy|related)")`..

Comment: Btw, is is possible to save the content as txt format, but it will look like in html format? If use p.get_text(strip=true), it's all together. If take out strip=true, which remain p.get_text, it has one to three space(break lines) between each line

Comment: @MichaelLin sure, but let's address this in a separate question, consider creating one. Thanks.

Comment: I solved it by adding p.get_text(strip=True) + str('\n\n')

Comment: I have another complex task....I just post the question, thank you for your help.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232216/beautifulsoup-parse-every-html-files-in-a-folder