# beautifulsoup parse every html files in a folder webscraping

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

My task is to read every html file from a directory. Conditions are to find whether each file contains tags

```
(1) <strong>OO</strong>  
(2) <strong>QQ</strong>
```

Then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `write` function is nested in the `for` loop, that's why you write multiple lines to your `index.txt`, just move the `write` out of the loop and put all your parti text to a variable `parti_names` like this:

```
participants = soup.find(find_participant)
parti_names = ""
for parti in participants.find_next_siblings("p"):
    if parti.find("strong", text=re.compile(r"(Operator)")):
        break
    parti_names += parti.get_text(strip=True)+","
    print parti.get_text(strip=True)

indexFile = open('index.txt', 'a+')
indexFile.write(filename + ', ' + title.get_text(strip=True) + ticker.get_text(strip=True) + ', ' + d_date.get_text(strip=True) + ', ' + parti_names + '\n' )
indexFile.close()
```

**Update:**

You can work with `basename` to get the file name:

```
from os.path import basename

# you can call it directly with basename
print(basename("C:/Users/.../output/100107-.html"))
```

Output:

```
100107-.html
```

Comment: I have another problem that I only want filename, but output gave me path+filename. I just updated the code.